# Страница 404 при нажатии на кнопку формы

Tags: php, phpstorm

Только начал работать в *PhpStorm* и столкнулся с такой проблемой, что при нажатии на кнопку "Apply" *Firefox* пишет `404 not found`, а *Opera* вообще не реагирует.

Решил скопировать этот же код и запустить его через обычный текстовый редактор. Всё работает. Возможно, кто - то сталкивался с подобной проблемой. Буду очень благодарен.

P.S. В *Google* искал решение, многие пишут об изменении некоторых параметров в файле `php.ini`. Не помогло.
   test.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>MyTitle</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method = 'POST' action = "obr.php">
        <p><input type = "text" name = "field"></p>
        <p><input type = 'submit' name = 'apply' value = 'Aply'></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html
```

obr.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["apply"])){
    echo "The button is pressed";
}
else {
    echo "Press the button";
}
?>
```

Comment: Не стоит юзать сервак от шторма, лучше поднять аля опенсервер

Answer (score 1):

Чаше всего 404 возникает, если в action указана неверная ссылка. И надо просто указать путь к файлу правильно.

Но у автора была другая проблема. В PhpStorm, а точнее в его встроенном сервере. В [этом](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207255485-No-POST-values-caught) топике её обсуждают. Как пишут в конце, её вроде бы пофиксиле но в моей версии 2017.3 всё ещё воспроизводится. В этом же топики пишут как её временно пофиксить. Обходной путь это не использовать встроенный сервер, а использовать Apache/nginx/IIS или что то другое.

Answer (score -1):

У вас не указан параметр `action` в теге `form`

Соответственно, этот ваш `submit`, как бы говорит форме "давай ка, отправляйся!", а форма такая - "А куда отправляться то? Я не знаю, вот на тебе 404!"

Comment: красиво стелишь :DD

Comment: Странно, но я всегда думал, что если не указывать обработчик формы, то эта же страница и будет обработчиком формы, но не суть. Я добавил обработчик, но все та же ошибка...

Comment: @SergeiM. код в вопросе обновите.

Comment: Так же интересно, что firefox сразу же пишет 404..., а opera просто выводит сообщение, указанное в else.

Comment: @SergeiM. Попробуйте через консоль разработчика в Firefox посмотреть, куда идет переход и попробовать самостоятельно пройти по этой ссылке.

Comment: В пекло firefox. В консоли разработчика пишет java-script ошибку. Решил установить Chromium. Тут ситуация обстоит лучше. Редирект идет на обработчик без проблем, вот только даже при нажатии кнопки выбивает исключение else.

Comment: так и должно быть. Ваша форма не содержит в себе элементов с именем **apply**. Кнопка с *sumit* не является частью данных формы.

Answer (score -2):

Когда форма отправляется на сервер, управление данными передается программе, заданной атрибутом **action** тега `<form>`. Ну и где у вас атрибут **action** ?

Comment: Добавление обработчика проблему не решило, увы...

Comment: Есть такое понятие как абсолютный и относительный путь. Если вы неправильно указываете положение "obr.php", ошибка сохранится. Попробуйте написать `action = "http://myhost/obr.php"`. Из браузера перейдите по ссылке. Ошибки быть не должно

Comment: Ну у меня файл с формой лежит в той же директории, что и сам обработчик. Безусловно, я так же пытался полностью вставить путь к обработчику. Не сработало... Но то, форма видит обработчик показала opera. Т.К. при нажатии на кнопку, этот браузер выбил текст, указанный в else

Comment: Зайдите через бразуер firefox напрямую на страницу **obr.php**. На всякий случай нажмите F5

Comment: Хм, интересная штука получается. При заходе на страницу обработчика напрямую выдает сообщение, указанное в else. Но, при этом передает какие-то GET параметры. А при переходе через форму, этих GET - параметров нет и 404 Page not found...

Comment: Но, при обновлении 404 страницы, то же выбивает исключение else

Answer (score -3):

Ошибка 404 означает, что страница не найдена, то есть её нет

Comment: А почему PhpStorm пытается открыть в обозревателе несуществующую страницу?